# Angular 9 Reactive Form - Array Form - selecting a value to fill automatically other cells in the same row

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor, ngmodel

I am continuing my learning curve in Angular and I got stuck again and I was wondering if someone can help me a bit.

**Scenario**
I got a form and inside the form a table.
The table contains many cells but it starts with the user selecting a value from the dropdown. Once the user selects a value, many other cells will be filled automatically (based on the cell selected).

**The Problem**
It seems that by using Reactive forms, I got into a different kind of trouble as onchanges does not work, I tried subscribing the arrayform to the observable but all I got now is object:object

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let itemrow of myorderForm.get('itemRows')['controls']; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <td>
    <input formControlName="orderLineNumber"  type="text" placeholder="{{ i + 1 }}">
  </td>
  <td>
    <select  formControlName="productName" input id="productName" [name]="productName" type="text">
        <option *ngFor="let thisproduct of allproducts;" value="thisproduct">{{thisproduct.productName}}</option>
     </select>                                  
   </td>
   <td> 
     <input formControlName="productScaleUoM" id="productScaleUoM" [name]="itemrow.productScaleUoM+ '_' + i" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="itemrow.productScaleUoM" placeholder="{{valueScale}}">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input formControlName="pack_quantity"  id="pack_quantity" [name]="itemrow.pack_quantity+ '_' + i" type="text"   [(ngModel)]="itemrow.pack_quantity" placeholder="{{valuePack}}">
    </td>
</tr>
```

The TS file looks like:

```js
addNewRow() {
  this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows());
}

onChangeObj(newObj) {
  this.productname[0] = newObj;
  this.valueScale = this.productname[0].productScaleUoM
  this.valuePack = this.productname[0].pack_quantity
}

deleteRow(index: number) {
  this.formArr.removeAt(index);
}
formControlValueChanged() {
//Just testing to see if I get the value of the product name
    this.myorderForm.get('itemRows').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.formattedMessage = `My name is ${val}.`;
      console.log("What is formatted message here", this.formattedMessage)
    });
```

Again, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don’t mix ngModel with formcontrols.. either go for a temate based form or for a reactive form. You cannot mix them.

Comment: thanks @MikeOne I changed now the code to get rid of the template based, but not I am struggling to get the subscription to correct check the changes to the form array. All I get is Object:object  when changing the selection. is this the way a reactive form should work just for autocomplete other fields in a form in angular?

Comment: Try stuff with console.log in your component and else with the json pipe in your template (to prevent [object object]..

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, You should
add few things like:

```
<select (change)="onChangeFunction($event)" >
```

function in the  tag and add

```
<option [value]="thisproduct">
```

Now call the function

```
onChangeFunction(data:any){
this.list=data;
console.log(this.list); //here you will get all the data on change event
}
```

Please comment if you stuck again.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for the help, I made the changes you suggested and indeed in the list I get lots of data but not really the data that I need. My goal at this point is t o obtain the same results I was obtained when using the NgModel. Using that method  I was getting: onChangeObj(newObj){ 
    console.log("what is newobj here", newObj);
   this.productname[0] = newObj;
    this.valueScale = this.productname[0].productScaleUoM
    this.valuePack = this.productname[0].pack_quantity. How can achieve that using just reactive forms?

Comment: Hi, try this , [value]="thisproduct.productName" . Whatever you will pass in [value] , that data you will get in console.log(this.list). I hope it will work.

Comment: Hi, still not working, this is what I am getting: Event {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target: select#productName.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid, currentTarget: select#productName.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid, eventPhase: 2, …}
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false

Comment: You will get your value under currentTarget -> value ,try this.  There one more way to get exact value, instead of $event you can put hisproduct.productName , but I prefer first one.

Comment: with that option I get another error...error TS2339: Property 'thisproduct' does not exist on 
type 'FullOrderComponent'. Also why the place holder of <td>
                                            <input id="orderLineNumber" formControlName="orderLineNumber"  type="text" placeholder="{{i + 1}}">
                                        </td> does not get instanciated in the formarray? I must be missing something fundamental as the inputs don't get recorded...I really appreciate your help. My goal is to be able to populate a number of fields automatically as soon as the user selects option

Comment: Dude , you will simply get the data from this.list, then reach to  currentTarget -> value

Comment: I got that bit now...instead of $event I used productname, I will keep trying with the rest